# MYSQL EntityFramework MVVM SaveChanges() with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, mvvm

i'm using VS2017 and created a C# WPF MVVM app with MYSQL entityframework.
In my view and view model of USERS(utenti) i binded and observable collection to a Datagrid.
Everything works fine, and when i change a cell in a row i use SaveChanges() to save into the db the updated data.
The only problem is when i add a row to my datagrid. when i save nothing happens.
SaveChanges() works only if i modify an existing row, not if i add a row.
Do you know why? I paste the code of my ViewModel

```
namespace LegalNote.ViewModels
   {
    class UCAccountsVM : BaseViewModel
    {
        legalnoteEntities legEnt = new legalnoteEntities();
        public UCAccountsVM()
        {
                List<utenti> listaUtenti = (from recordset in legEnt.utenti
                               where recordset.id >= 0
                               orderby recordset.id
                               select recordset).ToList();


                AccountsList = new ObservableCollection<utenti>(listaUtenti);
        }

        private ObservableCollection<utenti> accountsList;
        public ObservableCollection<utenti> AccountsList
        {
            get
            {
                return accountsList;
            }
            set
            {
                accountsList = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("AccountsList");
            }
        }

        private ICommand saveData;
        public ICommand SaveData
        {
            get
            {
                if (saveData == null)
                    saveData = new RelayCommand(o => salvaDati());
                return saveData;
            }
        }

        private void salvaDati()
        {
            legEnt.SaveChanges();
            
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The observable collection you are creating will contain references to the entities you have loaded, but adding an item to the observable collection does *not* in any way tell EF to create a new entity. You need to handle that action yourself to find items in the observable collection that have been added (or removed) then go to EF to add or remove entities from the DbSet.

Comment: understood. Thanks